# nodejs: does a find query to select n last records need to run asynchronously

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I am a newbie in nodejs. I want to fetch n last records from mongo and write them to a socket when a(n android) client connects.
I wrote some code and it was okay when I tested it on a vps i had, but, after moving to new vps a problem appeared.
When the first client connects to the socket, it does not get the records. However, if a second client connects to the socket the find query runs again and the first client can see the related emit, but, not for second client!

I added a log after the io.emit command and it runs for every client connecting.

I also added another emit that just sends a test text and it delivered to client as soon as he connected.

My code:

```
const express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    app = express(),
    server = http.createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Chat Server is running on port ......')
});


var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ChatMessage = require('./chatmessage');
var chatsdb = "mongodb://localhost:27017/chatsdb"
mongoose.connect(chatsdb, {useNewUrlParser: true});
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
    console.log('Mongoose connected!')
});
mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Mongoose default connection error:' + err);
});


io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    let userId = socket.id;

    console.log('user ' + userId + ' connected');//it always run
    io.emit('connected_message', {"message_text": "ok!" , "user_id":userId});//it always run

    ChatMessage.find().sort({created_at:-1}).limit(10).exec(function (err, posts) {
        let list_of_messages = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
            if (posts[i] != null) {
                let message = new ChatMessage({"message_text": posts[i].message_text, "name": posts[i].name , "created_at": posts[i].created_at});
                list_of_messages.push(message);
            }
        }

        io.emit('last_fifty_message', list_of_messages); 
        console.log("list_of_messages:" + list_of_messages); //it always run
    });

});


server.listen(50000, () => {
    console.log('Node app is running on port 50000')

});
```

and it's ChatMessage class:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ChatMessageSchema = new Schema({
name : { type: String, require:true },
    message_text    : { type: String , require:true  },
     created_at : { type:Date  , default: Date.now },
    message_id : { type: Number  , autoIncrement:true }
});

ChatMessageSchema.pre('save',function(next){
    this.created_at = new Date();
    console.log('this.created_at : '+this.created_at)
    next();
});


var ChatMessage = mongoose.model('ChatMessage' , ChatMessageSchema);

module.exports = ChatMessage;
```

I don't understand. If find records is a long process, how is it logged but not emitted and why is it emitted for clients that have connected already?

Does it need to run asynchronously? Can I use async/await or callbacks or ...??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `io.emit`, `io.emit` is sending to all connected clients

For emitting only to the connected socket use `socket.emit`

---

By the way, you should check if `error` Isn’t null